Rotate a forest tree
I would like you to help me please. I am drawing some syntactic phrase structure trees using the forest package, option linguistics. The problem is that when the trees grow, they do not fit in the page. So, I wanted to rotate them. The problem is that when I use the grow option, the tree rotates, but the nodes don't rotate along with it. Could  anyone help me? Here is my minimal code :
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}

\ex. \begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=10mm, inner sep=0, l=0, grow=0}
[IP
    [DP[The cat, roof]]
    [I$'$[VP[scratched the furniture, roof]]]
]
\end{forest}


\end{document}

But this is what I would like to achieve :


Dear @cfr, here is the issue.

Don't change the tree, rotate the page.  Linguistic trees aren't designed to be displayed sideways.

The problem is that in the actual document, there is text on the same page.

I don't think this is a good idea, but you could simply put the tree inside a \rotatebox command:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}
This is some text.
\ex. 
\rotatebox{90}{\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=10mm, inner sep=0,}
[IP
    [DP[The cat, roof]]
    [I$'$[VP[scratched the furniture, roof]]]
]
\end{forest}}

This is some more text.
\end{document}



Thanks. This is a solution and it is very simple. Thanks a lot.

I suggested sidewaysfigure. Why is that not a good idea?

@cfr sidewaysfigure isn't the right environment, since trees in linguistics aren't figures that float, but numbered examples. So the sideways environment would also work (which is essentially what my solution is). But I don't really like putting a tree on its side like that. It's hard to read. If a tree was very large and needed to take up a landscape page, then putting it on its own page and rotating the page would be a better solution.

I thought that's what sidewaysfigure did. But, actually, I meant something like: given that it has to be rotated. I can't say I'd rotate a tableau either but, if I had to, I'd want it on its own page. I don't like rotating things, but I like it even less on non-rotated pages. (Headers and footers are OK non-rotated but, if it is that big, they may be absent anyway.) But how do you put it on its own page without letting it float?

@cfr We totally agree on the "when to rotate" conditions. If the tree is big enough to fit on a page, then I would use the pdflscape package and issue a \clearpage before it.

@AlanMunn Oh, OK. Linguists' trees -> typeset as tableau. So they are proofs rather than illustrations? I've just never had a tableau too wide. The problem is when they get too long, so only breaking helps. I don't really know what I'd do if one was too wide. I've used too-wide trees, but not tableaux.

@cfr Definitely more like proofs than illustrations for sure.
